# I want to create interface for dig

Tags: go

I'm a novice in golang.
I want to abstract from the implementation of the service container:

```
type Container interface {
    Provide(constructor interface{}, opts ...interface{}) error
    Invoke(function interface{}, opts ...interface{}) error
}
```

but an error occurs:

```
#13 0.387 cmd/app/main.go:26:40: cannot use container (type *dig.Container) as type application.Container in argument to application.NewApplication:
#13 0.387       *dig.Container does not implement application.Container (wrong type for Invoke method)
#13 0.387               have Invoke(interface {}, ...dig.InvokeOption) error
#13 0.387               want Invoke(interface {}, ...interface {}) error
```

What am I doing wrong?
How I can declare interface correct?

Comment: as the error says, your opts has type `...interface{}` and should be `...dig.InvokeOption`

Comment: I know, but I don't want to be dependent on dig into my application layer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Cannot use container (type *dig.Container) as type application.Container in argument to application.NewApplication:
       *dig.Container does not implement application.Container (wrong type for Invoke method)
               have Invoke(interface {}, ...dig.InvokeOption) error
               want Invoke(interface {}, ...interface {}) error
```

This means `*dig.Container` doesn't satisfy the interface `application.Container`.  It goes on to explain that `application.Container` requires the `Invoke` method to take a variadic list of `interface{}`, but `*dig.Container` takes a  variadic list of `dig.InvokeOption`.

Even though an empty interface can store any type, that does not mean that any slice type is automatically also a slice of empty interfaces (That's a big motivation for Generics, which should come out soon).

I remember being confused by this myself.  Consder this code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type T struct{}

func main() {
    var Ts = []T{
    T{}, T{}, T{},
    }
    fmt.Println(Ts...)    
}
```

It will not compile, even thought each individual `T` satisfies `interface{}` because a `[]T` is *not* an `[]interface{}`:

> ./prog.go:13:16: cannot use Ts (type []T) as type []interface {} in argument to fmt.Println

The easiest solution here would be to make `dig.Container`'s `Invoke` function match the `Invoke` signature of `application.Container`.  You can still pass it a list of `*dig.InvokeOption`s, which individually satisfy `interface{}`.   You'll still have to convert the `interface{}`s back to `*dig.InvokeOption`s within `dig.Container.Invoke`.

Comment: ok, I understand, thank you,
but how I can resolve this? its possible without Generics and dependency from dig?

Comment: I think, I should implement an adapter

Comment: There's a very specific solution in the answer.   What about it can be improved to be more understandable?

Comment: dig (go.uber.org/dig) - is not my code :) I can't change it signature :)

Comment: Then yeah, I would wrap the function with an adaptor function that had the appropriate signature, then cast the incoming interfaces to `*dig.InvokeOption` and pass it on through.